# How to change the color of sphere objects dynamically (used SceneBuilder in Autodesk forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on the example from [Custom models in Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer) blog by Petr Broz. I am facing issue in updating the color of sphere objects dynamically. I am getting the value of sphere's color from a json file like this `"color": "#FF0000"`. I have created 3 spheres and I am getting the color of first sphere for the rest also. Why the color is not updating for the other spheres? If the problem is on using same material then I tried giving the sphereMaterial in array also as shown below. Is that wrong or how can i update the color?

```js
var spherecolor='';
var sphereMaterial = [];
const button = document.getElementById('button-geometry');
  button.addEventListener('click', async function () {
  const sceneBuilder = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
  const modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({ conserveMemory: true, modelNameOverride: 'My Custom Model' });
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfSphere;i++) {
    addGeometry(modelBuilder, jsonGeomConfig.geom[i].dbId, i);
  }
});
function addGeometry(modelBuilder, dbId, i) {
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 8, 10));
  //Getting spherecolor from json file
  spherecolor = jsonGeomConfig.geom[i].color;
  sphereMaterial[i] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: spherecolor });
  const sphereTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
    new THREE.Vector3(jsonGeomConfig.geom[i].Position.posX, jsonGeomConfig.geom[i].Position.posY, jsonGeomConfig.geom[i].Position.posZ),
    new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2)
  );
  modelBuilder.addMaterial('MyCustomMaterial', sphereMaterial[i]);
  const sphereGeomId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(sphereGeometry);
  const sphereFragId = modelBuilder.addFragment(sphereGeomId, 'MyCustomMaterial', sphereTransform);
  modelBuilder.changeFragmentsDbId(sphereFragId, dbId);
}
```

Comment: Setting color using hex is fine with Three.js - Not knowing what's inside `jsonGeomConfig`  I can't figure out what exactly went wrong ... just tested with my own code and everything worked fine ...

Comment: jsonGeomConfig has the response from json file. I am getting the color of the sphere from that file. I have created three sphere objects where I am getting the first sphere color for the rest also, I will share what i have given in the json file (jsonGeomConfig)

Comment: `{
  "NumOfSphere": "3",
  "geom": [
    {
      "dbId": "123",
      "color": "#FF0000",
      "Position": {
        "posX": "-5",
        "posY": "-1",
        "posZ": "2.5"
      }
    },
    {
      "dbId": "1234",
      "color": "#0000FF",
      "Position": {
        "posX": "-5",
        "posY": "-0.8",
        "posZ": "1.8"
      }
    },
    {
      "dbId": "12345",
      "color": "green",
      "Position": {
        "posX": "-3.5",
        "posY": "-1.5",
        "posZ": "1.8"
      }
    }
  ]  
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to give the materials with different colors different names ... otherwise it'd get overridden - see [this](https://jsbin.com/loxugac/edit?js) live environment:

```
  modelBuilder.addMaterial('MyCustomMaterial'+i, sphereMaterial[i]);
  const sphereGeomId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(sphereGeometry);
  const sphereFragId = modelBuilder.addFragment(sphereGeomId, 'MyCustomMaterial'+i, sphereTransform);
```